# VScode Is there a way to fold code by a special comment prefix?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using snakefile that got out of control. I kinda like that it is one file, but even with all the rules folded I have to deal with a long scrollbar.
Is there a way/extension to allow code to collapse by special comment prefix?

```py
#% normalize data
rule count:
    ...
# some comment that should 
rule divide:
    ...
rule drop_duplicates:
    ...
#% statistical tests
rule ttest:
   ...
#% output
rule all:
    ...
rule zip:
    ...
```

this way I could fold it into:

```py
#% normalize data
#% statistical tests
#% output
```

I think that would be easier to handle than dealing with multiple files.

thank you,

tried searching online, and found an extension that should do that but could not make it work (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zokugun.explicit-folding).
if someone wants to check my zokugun explicit-folding rules i tried:

```json
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {
        "rocket": "linux",
        "Jovian": "linux",
        "JovianLocal": "linux"
    },
    "git.ignoreLegacyWarning": true,
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
    "terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false,
    "audioCues.taskCompleted": "on",
    "audioCues.taskFailed": "on",
    "notebook.lineNumbers": "on",
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "jupyter.askForKernelRestart": false,
    "[python]": {
        "explicitFolding.rules": [
            {
                "beginRegex": "#%%",
                "endRegex": "##%",
                "autofold": true
            },
            {
                "indentation": true,
                "offSide": true
            }
        ],
    "explicitFolding.autoFold": "1",
    },
    "explicitFolding.rules": [
    
    ],
}
```

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding ?